# The list feature does not work, and somehow it is strangely displayed in console.log() Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase

I wanted to use a list to store data and display it later. But when I use  `ListOfName.lenth` I see:
[Photo of console][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ43X.png

But when `Console.log(ListOfName)` i see [Photo of List in console][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ0Kk.png

Home Component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs";
import {FirebaseService} from "../services/firebase.service";
import {JSDocTagName} from "@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-homework',
  templateUrl: './homework.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homework.component.css']
})
export class HomeworkComponent implements OnInit {
  // tagName = `<div><app-tables-homework>x</app-tables-homework></div>`;
  constructor( public firebaseservise:FirebaseService) { }
  ListOfName:string[] =[]
    TempName = `<h1>dasdasd</h1>`
    tagName = ``
    Temp = 1
 GetData(){
 this.ListOfName = this.firebaseservise.GetDataFromTestAll(this.ListOfName)
  console.log(this.ListOfName.length)
   console.log(this.ListOfName)
}
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }




}
```

GetDataFromTestAll:

```
   GetDataFromTestAll(Tempe:string[]){
    this.ListOfName=[]
    this.FirebaseData.database.ref("Test").get().then(res =>{

      res.forEach(Groups =>{

        if (localStorage.getItem('Group') ==  Groups.key){
          this.FirebaseData.database.ref(`Test/`+Groups.key).get().then(r=>{
            r.forEach(l=>{
              this.ListOfName.push(String(l.key))



            })



          })

        }
        else {

        }

      })

    })

     return this.ListOfName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because GetDataFromTestAll is **Asynchronous**. In yor code, you don't have the value until the promise return something.

Try to put *console.log()* here:

```
 GetDataFromTestAll(Tempe:string[]){
    this.ListOfName=[]
    this.FirebaseData.database.ref("Test").get().then(res =>{

      res.forEach(Groups =>{

        if (localStorage.getItem('Group') ==  Groups.key){
          this.FirebaseData.database.ref(`Test/`+Groups.key).get()
          .then(r=>{
            r.forEach(l=>{
              this.ListOfName.push(String(l.key))
            })
            
            console.log(this.ListOfName) // <-- Here you have your whole ListOfName
            return this.ListOfName // <-- You should do the return of data here
          })
        } else {}
      })
    })
     
}
```

If you make the return at that point, it will probably complain that the function *GetDataFromTestAll* does not always has return...
If it gives you a lot of trouble, it would be better if you treated the function as an observable and subscribed to it, but that's a different problem.